# Proving that a set is not negation complete

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I'm working through an exercise which involves negation completeness.

Let $S = \{R\}$. Let x and y be distinct variables. Suppose we have the set $\phi = \{Rx \vee Ry\}$. Show "Not $\phi \vdash Rx$" and "Not $\phi \vdash \neg Rx$". In other words, I need to show that $\phi$ is not negation complete.

The only idea that I had was to do this by a case-by-case basis assuming each one is true.

For example:

Case 1: Suppose $\phi \vdash Rx$. This suggests that $\phi$ does not hold when $\neg Rx$. Consider $\neg Rx \wedge Ry$ where $\phi$ holds but $\neg Rx$, thus we have a contradiction.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are. For 1, you have to show that $Rx \lor Ry \nvDash Rx$ and to do this, you have to find an *interpretation* for $R$ and an *assignment* for $x$ and $y$ such that $Rx \lor Ry$ holds and $Rx$ do not. This can be done, choosing for $y$ a value such that $R$ holds of it and for $x$ a value such that $R$ does not.

Comment: An easy model can be found in $\mathbb N$ interpreting $Rx$ as $x=0$; thus, it is enough to choose a *variable assignment* assigning $1$ to $x$ and $0$ to $y$.